# Accurate countdown timer

Tags: javascript

I modified a code from for an accurate timer from Stack Overflow to create a countdown timer:

```js
countdownTimer(5); // seconds

function countdownTimer(duration) {
  duration *= 1000; // convert to ms
  let interval = 1000; // ms
  let expected = Date.now() + interval;
  setTimeout(step, interval);

  function step() {
    if (duration <= 0) {      
      console.log("Ended");
      return;
    }
    let dt = Date.now() - expected; // the drift (positive for overshooting)
    if (dt > interval) {
      // something really bad happened. Maybe the browser (tab) was inactive?
      // possibly special handling to avoid futile "catch up" run
    } // do what is to be done

    console.log(duration / 1000);
    expected += interval;
    duration -= 1000;

    setTimeout(step, Math.max(0, interval - dt)); // take into account drift
  }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to improve it?

Also, one of my concerns is regarding this part:

```
if (dt > interval) {
  // something really bad happened. Maybe the browser (tab) was inactive?
  // possibly special handling to avoid futile "catch up" run
} // do what is to be done
```

What am I supposed to do to handle the countdown and keep it counting correctly in case this happens without stopping the timer?

Answer (score 2):

### You ask

> *"What am I supposed to do to handle the countdown and keep it counting correctly in case this happens without stopping the timer?"*

Ignore the fact that the interval was longer than expected as there is nothing you can do. See example snippet below.

All that matters is the time remaining till the alarm should fire.

To do that you just keep the time of the alarm `alarmTime = Date.now() + duration * 1000`. The time till the alarm is then `alarmTime - Date.now()`

If the time is past the alarm bad luck.

### Bug.

If the `duration` is less than `interval` then the function will not fire until `interval` time has passed. Best to call `step` immediately.

### Design

The design of the function is very poor. It will lose time (not might lose time) as setTimeout does not guarantee that the timeout is what you ask.

You should keep track of when the duration is up, rather than count (estimate, guess)  how much time has passed.

### Example

Uses [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance_API) for timing. It provides a high res timer that starts when the page is loaded.

Uses callbacks to call timing ticks (intervals) and alarm, far better than logging to a console.

Note that the timer will fire the alarm up to 10ms before time, as timeout may not give you an interval of less than 10ms (depending on many factors)

```js
const timeTill = 10; // in seconds

const MS_PER_SEC = 1000;
const ALARM_OFFSET = 10;  // in ms. 
const MIN_INTERVAL = 100;  // in ms
const alarm = () => tickerEl.textContent = "Alarm Alarm Alarm. Time up!";
const ticker = till => tickerEl.textContent = "In: " + Math.round(till / MS_PER_SEC) + " seconds"

countdownTimer(timeTill, alarm, ticker);
alarmEl.textContent = timeTill + " second countdown started"

function countdownTimer(duration, callback, tickCallback, interval = 1000) {
    interval = Math.max(MIN_INTERVAL, isNaN(interval) ? MIN_INTERVAL : interval);
    const alarmTime = performance.now() + duration * MS_PER_SEC;
    tick();
    function tick() {
        const timeTillAlarm = alarmTime - performance.now();
        if (timeTillAlarm < ALARM_OFFSET) {
            callback?.();
        } else {
            tickCallback?.(timeTillAlarm);
            setTimeout(tick, Math.min(alarmTime - performance.now(), interval));
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="alarmEl"></div>
<div id="tickerEl"></div>
```

**NOTE**: That using any of `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `requestAnimationFrame`... there is no way to guarantee the countdown will be accurate or even fire at all.  If the alarm is important DO NOT USE a browser app to set an alarm!